# SwiftUI - MenuPickerStyle not working, but any other style works

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to use [`MenuPickerStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menupickerstyle) on a [`Picker`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker). However, nothing happens when I click it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedColor = "Red"
    var colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Choose a color", selection: $selectedColor) {
                ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
            
            Text("You selected \(selectedColor)")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Nothing happens when pressing "Choose a color"]

That was on the simulator. If I use the Live Preview, it works:

[image: Pressing "Choose a color" presents a menu with selectable options]

If I replace `MenuPickerStyle()` with `WheelPickerStyle()`, it also works:

[image: Picker displayed in wheel style with selectable options]

I'm on Xcode `Version 12.5 (12E262)` and using the iPhone 12 (iOS 14.5) simulator. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: That works fine for me on iPhone 12 Simulator and on real device.  Xcode 12.5.1

Comment: @rbaldwin just tested on real device and it works for me too, huh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a simulator bug. It works fine on a real device.

Comment: I have the issue on Preview, simulator and real devices... even now that I am on iOS 15.0.2

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for "MenuPickerStyle" says: "Do not use this type directly. Instead, use menu."

So try ".pickerStyle(.menu)"

Comment: I'm on Xcode 13. However the docs mention ios 14+ and macos11+, so maybe, just maybe it is also available on Xcode 12.

Comment: Nope, `Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'menu'`